# Carregando dados do login em outro subdominio

Tags: php, mysql

no sistema que estou fazendo existe 3 paineis, sendo uma tabela de users para cada painel e o site publico. Quando o user faz login em algum dos três paineis, e voltasse a acessar o site publico, apareceria mais informações. 
Resumindo é um "faça login para ver". Cada painel fica em um subdominio e o publico no principal.
Eu não estou conseguindo fazer retornar a informação que este user está logado para o site publico, e sinceramente não sei se há como fazer isso.

**HEAD.php**

```
<?php
    $host = 'localhost';
    $usuario = 'psaude';
    $senha = '';
    $banco = 'psaude';
    $conn = @mysql_connect($host, $usuario, $senha) or die(mysql_error());
    $db = mysql_select_db($banco, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
    $charset = mysql_set_charset('utf8');
    function __autoload($class)
    {
        require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../class/{$class}.class.php");
    }
    $objLogin = new Login();
    if (!$objLogin->verificar('/login'))
        exit;

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE chns = {$objLogin->getID()}");
    $usuario = mysql_fetch_object($query);
    $user_mostra = $usuario->id;
    $user_nome = $usuario->nome;
    $user_cnhs = $usuario->chns;
?>
```

**CLASS.php(Login.class.php)**

```
<?php

class Login {

    private $tabela, $campoID, $campoLogin, $campoSenha, $campoStatus, $campoAtivo;

    function  __construct($tabela = 'users', $campoID = 'chns', $campoStatus = 'status', $campoAtivo = 'dob', $campoLogin = 'email', $campoSenha = 'senha') {

            // Iniciando sessão
            @session_start();

            // Definindo atributos
            $this->tabela = $tabela;
            $this->campoID = $campoID;
            $this->campoLogin = $campoLogin;
            $this->campoSenha = $campoSenha;
            $this->campoStatus = $campoStatus;
            $this->campoAtivo = $campoAtivo;
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Retornando login do usuário que está na sessão
     *
     * @access  public
     * @return  string
     */

    function getLogin() {
        return $_SESSION[$this->campoLogin];
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Retornando ID do usuário que está na sessão
     *
     * @access  public
     * @return  integer
     */

    function getID() {
        return $_SESSION[$this->campoID];
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Trata as informações recebidas, procura o usuário no banco de dados e, se encontrado,
         * registra as informações na sessão.
     *
     * @access  public
         * @param   string
     * @param   string
         * @param   string
     * @return  boolean
     */

    function logar($login, $senha, $status, $dob, $redireciona = null) {
        // Tratando as informações
        $login = mysql_real_escape_string($login);
        $senha = mysql_real_escape_string($senha);
        $status = mysql_real_escape_string($status);

        // Verifica se o usuário existe
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT {$this->campoID}, {$this->campoLogin}, {$this->campoSenha}, {$this->campoAtivo}
                             FROM {$this->tabela}
                             WHERE {$this->campoLogin} = '{$login}' AND {$this->campoSenha} = '{$senha}' AND {$this->campoAtivo} = 'ativo'");
        // $query_1 = mysql_query("UPDATE status = '$status' WHERE uid = '{$this->campoID}'");

        // Se encontrado um usuário
        if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
        {
            // Instanciando usuário
            $usuario = mysql_fetch_object($query);

            // Registrando sessão
            $_SESSION[$this->campoID] = $usuario->{$this->campoID};
            $_SESSION[$this->campoLogin] = $usuario->{$this->campoLogin};
            $_SESSION[$this->campoSenha] = $usuario->{$this->campoSenha};
            $_SESSION[$this->campoAtivo] = $usuario->{$this->campoAtivo};

            // Se informado redirecionamento
            if ($redireciona !== null)
                header("Location: {$redireciona}");
            else
                return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Verifica se o usuário está logado
     *
     * @access  public
         * @param   string
     * @return  boolean
     */

    function verificar($redireciona = null) {
        // Se as sessões estiverem setadas
        if(isset($_SESSION[$this->campoID]) and isset($_SESSION[$this->campoLogin]) and isset($_SESSION[$this->campoSenha]))
            return true;
        else
        {
            if (headers_sent()) {
                die('<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=../login">');
            }else{
                exit(header("Location: /user.php"));
            }
            // Se informado redirecionamento
            if ($redireciona !== null)
                header("Location: {$redireciona}");

            return false;    
        }

    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Finaliza a sessão do usuário
     *
     * @access  public
         * @param   string
     * @return  void
     */

    function logout($redireciona = null) {
        // Limpa a Sessão
        $_SESSION = array();
        // Destroi a Sessão
        session_destroy();
        // Modifica o ID da Sessão
        session_regenerate_id();
        // Se informado redirecionamento
        if ($redireciona !== null)
            header("Location: {$redireciona}");
    }

}
?>
```

Ao digitar as informações no formulário, envia para o arquivo `logar` via post

**logar.php**

```
<?php
require_once('../config/conn.php');
$objLogin = new Login();
$login = $_POST['email'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];
$status = "";
$dob = "";
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$data_login = date("d/m/Y");
$hora_login = date("h:i");
if ($objLogin->logar($login, $senha, $status, $dob))
    // Retornando falso
        echo false; 
    else{
        // Retornando mensagem de erro
        echo 'Login ou senha inválidos. <br>Caso o problema persista, tente redefinir sua senha.';
    }
    $executa = "UPDATE users SET status = 'online', data_login = '$data_login', hora_login = '$hora_login' WHERE email = '$login'";
    $executaQr = mysql_query($executa) or die;
    if ($executaQr){    echo false; }
?>
```

**CONFIG.php**

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$usuario = 'root';
$senha = '';
$banco = 'psaude';
$conn = @mysql_connect($host, $usuario, $senha) or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db($banco, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
$charset = mysql_set_charset('utf8');
function __autoload($class)
{
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../class/{$class}.class.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Primeiro recomendo que leia: [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/).

Comment: `mysql_` is **dead**.

Comment: @vmsouza, eu sei que o `mysql_` está depreciado e está descontinuado, tanto que no painel adm eu uso PDO para fazer as inclusões, exclusões e buscas. Porém esse login eu uso há anos e nunca obtive problemas com o `mysql_`. Mas irei fazer atualizações futuras nos sites dos clientes assim que atualizar o código com `PDO`. Mas, voltando a pergunta, tem como fazer esse retorno de usuário logado no domínio principal mesmo feito login em um sub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar um cookie para verificar se o usuario está logado no subdomino ou no dominio principal. Para isso, basta que você crie um token, salve no banco de dados, e o coloque como um cookie para o navegador. Então a cada vez que você for verifica o login no site principal, basta checar se o cookie recebido no request existe no banco de dados. O cookie deve ter esse formato:

```
setcookie("token", $valor, tempo de duracao em milisegundos, "/", "www.dominoprincipal.com");
```

Para uma referencia da função setcookie consulte o [php.net](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setcookie.php).

Aplicando isso ao seu caso ficaria assim:

Login.class.php

```
function verificar($redireciona = null) {

        /*****************************************************************
         Check no banco se o token existe
        ******************************************************************/
        //a função tokenExiste faz uma consulta no banco e verifica 
        //se existe o campo token, e retorna um booleano
        $tokenExiste = tokenExiste($_COOKIE["token"]);
        if($tokenExiste){
             //se sim, set os dados da sessão
             return true;
        }

        // Se as sessões estiverem setadas
        if(isset($_SESSION[$this->campoID]) and isset($_SESSION[$this->campoLogin]) and isset($_SESSION[$this->campoSenha]))
            return true;
        else
        {
            if (headers_sent()) {
                die('<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=../login">');
            }else{
                exit(header("Location: /user.php"));
            }
            // Se informado redirecionamento
            if ($redireciona !== null)
                header("Location: {$redireciona}");

            return false;    
        }
}

function logar($login, $senha, $status, $dob, $redireciona = null) {
        // Tratando as informações
        $login = mysql_real_escape_string($login);
        $senha = mysql_real_escape_string($senha);
        $status = mysql_real_escape_string($status);

        // Verifica se o usuário existe
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT {$this->campoID}, {$this->campoLogin}, {$this->campoSenha}, {$this->campoAtivo}
                             FROM {$this->tabela}
                             WHERE {$this->campoLogin} = '{$login}' AND {$this->campoSenha} = '{$senha}' AND {$this->campoAtivo} = 'ativo'");
        // $query_1 = mysql_query("UPDATE status = '$status' WHERE uid = '{$this->campoID}'");

        // Se encontrado um usuário
        if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
        {
            // Instanciando usuário
            $usuario = mysql_fetch_object($query);

            // Registrando sessão
            $_SESSION[$this->campoID] = $usuario->{$this->campoID};
            $_SESSION[$this->campoLogin] = $usuario->{$this->campoLogin};
            $_SESSION[$this->campoSenha] = $usuario->{$this->campoSenha};
            $_SESSION[$this->campoAtivo] = $usuario->{$this->campoAtivo};

            /***********************************************************
             Configurando o cookie
            ************************************************************/
            //antes de imprimir qualquer conteudo html, set o cookie
            $valor = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));//gerar um valor unico

            setcookie("token", $valor, time()+3600, "/", "www.dominioprincipal.com");

            //salve a variavel $valor no banco de dados

            // Se informado redirecionamento
            if ($redireciona !== null)
                header("Location: {$redireciona}");
            else
                return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
}
```

Basicamente você precisa criar um novo campo na sua tabela de usuarios. Depois, sempre que um usuario se logar em um subdomino você cria um cookie, gerar um valor unico para ele ([uniqid](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.uniqid.php)), salva no banco, e usa a função setcookie para retorna-lo para o navegador do usuario. Dessa maneira, em verificações posteriores de login, dentro do dominio principal, ou dentro dos subdominios, você pode usar o valor do cookie enviado pelo navegador para verificar se o usuario fez login anteriormente, e carregar os dados de sessão necessarios. Como é informação sensivel você poderia usar ssl no seu site.

Como informação extra faço um recorte, tirado da documentação do php.net, dos parametros da função setcookie:

> name
>
> ```
> O nome do cookie. value
>
> O valor do cookie. Esse valor é guardado no computador do cliente; não guarde informação sensível. Supondo que o name seja
> ```
>
> 'nomedocookie', o valor pode ser lido través de
>   $_COOKIE['nomedocookie'] expire
>
> ```
> O tempo para o cookie expirar. Esse valor é uma timestamp Unix, portanto é o número de segundos desde a época (epoch). Em outras
> ```
>
> palavras, você provavelmente irá utilizar isso com a função time()
>   mais o número de segundos que você quer que ele expire. Ou você pode
>   utilizar a função mktime(). time()+60*60*24*30 irá configurar o cookie
>   para expirar em 30 dias. Se configurado para 0, ou omitido, o cookie
>   irá expirar ao fim da sessao (quando o navegador fechar).
>
> ```
>     Nota:
>
>     Você pode ver que o parâmetro expire recebe uma timestamp Unix, ao contrário do formato de data Wdy, DD-Mon-YYYY HH:MM:SS GMT,
> ```
>
> isso se dá porque o PHP faz essa conversão internamente.
>
> path
>
> ```
> O caminho no servidor aonde o cookie estará disponível. Se configurado para '/', o cookie estará dosponível para todo o domain.
> ```
>
> Se configurado para o diretório '/foo/', o cookie estará disponível
>   apenas dentro do diretório /foo/ e todos os subdiretórios como
>   /foo/bar do domain. O valor padrão é o diretório atual onde o cookie
>   está sendo configurado. domain
>
> ```
> O (sub)domínio para qual o cookie estará disponível. Definindo para um subdomínio (como 'www.example.com') deixará o cookie
> ```
>
> disponível para aquele subdomínio e todos os outros sub-domínios
>   abaixo dele (exemplo w2.www.example.com). Para deixar o cookie
>   disponível para todo o domínio (incluindo todos os subdomínios dele),
>   simplesmente defina o valor para o nome do domínio ('example.com',
>   nesse caso).
>
> ```
> Browsers antigos ainda implementam a » RFC 2109 e podem requerer um . no início para funcionar com todos os subdomínios. secure
>
> Indica que o cookie só podera ser transimitido sob uma conexão segura HTTPS do cliente. Quando configurado para TRUE, o cookie será
> ```
>
> enviado somente se uma conexão segura existir. No lado do servidor,
>   fica por conta do programador enviar esse tipo de cookie somente sob
>   uma conexão segura (ex respeitando $_SERVER["HTTPS"]). httponly
>
> ```
> Quando for TRUE o cookie será acessível somente sob o protocolo HTTP. Isso significa que o cookie não será acessível por linguagens de
> ```
>
> script, como JavaScript. É dito que essa configuração pode ajudar a
>   reduzir ou identificar roubos de identidade através de ataques do tipo
>   XSS (entretanto ela não é suportada por todos os browsers), mas essa
>   informação é constantemente discutida. Foi adicionada no PHP 5.2.0.
>   TRUE ou FALSE

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado, ficou muito mais dinâmico agora. Eu estava usando a url com um Token gerado no login e um Código que eu coloco em todos meus projetos como um keygen quando insere algo no banco, que é gerado pelo `time()`, definido como chns na tabela. A url ficava basicamente assim "?a=chns&t=keygen", eu usava ambos para localizar e confirmar os dados do usuário, agora estou usando o cookie para isso e a url fica limpa, sem "divulgar" essas informações ao usuário.