# Login em subdominio e retorna no dominio raiz

Tags: php, mysql

Estou empacado nessa parte para finalizar o projeto.
A teoria é a seguinte, você fez login em cliente.site.com, e acessa site.com e seus dados de login permanecem ativos, sem haver necessidade de logar em site.com.

Eu havia feito a mesma pergunta aqui, coloquei todo o código que estou usando nele atualmente, mas não obtive a resposta se há como obter esse retorno de usuário logado no "site.com" e como faz isso.

Resolvido na pergunta original:

[Carregando dados do login em outro subdominio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/266316/carregando-dados-do-login-em-outro-subdominio)

Comment: coloquei uma resposta na [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/266316/carregando-dados-do-login-em-outro-subdominio/267463#267463). Você poderia acrescentar esse texto na outra pergunta, ficaria mais explicativo.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Carregando dados do login em outro subdominio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/266316/carregando-dados-do-login-em-outro-subdominio)